# selenium rc open timeout because of popup

Tags: javascript, python, selenium, automated-tests, selenium-rc

I am testing a proxy which has returned a popup with username and password fields. Calling open_browser(url) should work, but the popup is showing prior to the main window opening and so open_browser times out, leaving a popup on the screen. Adding the username:password@url jumps past the auth popup, but that defeats part of the object of the test. Whats the JS I need to use to firstly see the popup and second interact with the session during the hanging call to open_browser before it fails with a timeout?

```
s = selenium('127.0.0.1',4444,"*chrome","http://example.com")
s.set_timeout(2000)
s.start()
try:
    s.open("/")     # timeout after 2s and screen shows the inaccessible popup! 
except:
    s.get_alert()     << exception, there were no alerts
    s.get_prompt()    << exception, there were no prompts
    print s.get_location()
    u'http://selenium-node:4444/selenium-server/core/Blank.html?start=true'
```

The popup has a label 'A username and password are being requested by
     http://myproxy-ip:885.

The site says "localauthserver"' and 2 text fields.

None of the s.get_all_* return anything useful. I need to learn some more javascript, but at this point I need help.

Comment: what happens if you remove the `*` from `htt*p://mysite.com` .. i've never seen an asterisk at the location before

Comment: the question submission required that I obfuscate the urls. The * was an attempt at obfuscation and were not part of the original work. I do not know the stackoverflow protocol for url-masking to avoid issues with clickable refs in the text. I did add a footnote in an attempt at explanation.